# Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, bcs

If you are working with a larger external list (more than 2000 items) in dev environment it works perfectly, but when you work in production environment, it throws error
"Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator. Correlation ID: ...........".
So start to working to fix the BCS limit through powershell.
When I enter below command in powershell I get error in cmd. Any idea?

```
PS C:\Program Files\Nintex\Nintex Workflow 2010> Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrott
leConfig -Identity Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -Scope ThrottleType I
tems Database-GUID-ServiceApplicationProxy 5222b2db-fdd1-43f5-accb-7f039155f654-
8000-default maximum 6000
Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Can
not convert the "Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig" value of type "System
.String" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.ThrottleConfi
g".
At line:1 char:50
+ Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -Identity <<<<  Get-SPBusinessDataCat
alogThrottleConfig -Scope ThrottleType Items Database-GUID-ServiceApplicationPr
oxy 5222b2db-fdd1-43f5-accb-7f039155f654-8000-default maximum 6000
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogT
   hrottleConfig], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.SharePo
   int.BusinessData.SharedService.SPSetSPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance there seems to be some issues in your PowerShell syntax. You specify another cmdlet as value for the `-Identity` parameter, and that won't work. Sharepoint is not really my expertise, but [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bcs/archive/2010/02/16/bcs-powershell-introduction-and-throttle-management.aspx) by lionelro on the msdn blogs looks like a good place to start. Especially since the start of the article describes your issue online appearing on the production environment. Hope it helps.